# How to get the Australian Time Zone using Javascript? (Not JQuery)

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, utc

I am trying to help a friend to get the Australian Time Zone for the University Assignment and finding difficulty.
Could someone point us in the right direction?
Thank you!

```
<script>
function Timezone() {
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours;
}
</script>

<p id="add"></p>
```

Comment: What issues are you running into? If you could be more specific maybe people can help. Also, an example on jsfiddle.net is always nice :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the Australian Time Zone"?  Australia has *multiple* time zones, and different offsets apply at different times of the year for some of them.  Read [time in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia), the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and my blog post, [What is a Time Zone](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/02/07/what-is-a-time-zone/).  Also consider watching my Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals).

Answer (score 5):

You simply use

```
let AuDate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"});
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code, looks like you are trying to get the current date and time of an Australian timezone. Lets say you want Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST) and you want the date displayed how they would in Australia DD-MM-YYYY then do the following:

```
var timestamp_UTC = new Date();
var readable_timestamp_AEST = timestamp_UTC.toLocaleDateString("en-AU", {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"}).replace(/\//g, "-") + ' ' + somestamp.toLocaleTimeString("en-AU", {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"});
```

"en-AU" is the `locales` argument which tells the `toLocalDateString` to display the date as DD-MM-YYYY and the second argument is for `options` (timeZone is just one such possible option). Info about `toLocalDateString` function can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Here is some information about the Date() function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Hope this clears up a few things around getting times and dates from the Date() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you mean. But before that i'd like to make 2 points:

1: The Timezone() function should be called somewhere.

```
<script>
  function Timezone() {
    var x = new Date();
    var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours;
  }
  Timezone();
</script>
```

2: The convention usually is that methods start with a lower case letter. Maybe `updateTimezone()` would be more appropriate.

Your question can be interpreted in 2 ways now:

- you want your timezone's offset in hours and for this the code above should work. `getTimezoneOffset()` is the way to go.
- you want a human readable name of your timezone, as you can see on my site [currentmillis.com](http://currentmillis.com) (in my case it says **GTB Summer**). You can look in my source code to see how i achieve this:

```
var s = date.toString();
var iOfP = s.indexOf('('); // index of parenthesis
if (iOfP < 0) {
  s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
} else {
  s = s.substring(iOfP+1, s.length-1);
}
if (s.length > 4 && s.lastIndexOf(" Time") == s.length-5){
  s = s.substring(0, s.length-5);
}
timezoneM.innerHTML = s;
```

This works because when you call toString() on the date the result should contain the full name of your timezone: [w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp)